# Cannot access custom properties on nested user control

Tags: asp.net

Ok, please understand the architecture here first.

- **OurMasterPage.aspx** has user control **Header.ascx**
- **Header.ascx** has a user control in it called **LandingPageTopNav**
- **LandingPageTopNav.ascx** has a public property named "LandingPage" that is there to be able to set by the user using this control.
- And I have a **Third.aspx** page in which I need to    set the LandingPageTopNav property to    a LandingPage object

The problem is that I can't get this to work in my ThirdPage.aspx.cs:

```
    Master.LandingPageTopNav.LandingPage = this.landingPage;
    Master.LandingPageTopNav.Visible = true;
```

And that is, I can't get the first line to work where I'm trying to reference the LandingPage property.  The second line is fine.  My Third.aspx definitely can reference my master page objects otherwise from code-behind.

Comment: "Header.ascx has a user control in it called LandingPageTopNav" by "called" do you mean that is the type name or the valie of the ID property? Please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd venture to guess that the LandingPageTopNav **property** of OurMasterPage doesn't return a value typed as LandingPageTopNav.  It probably returns the correct control typed as something more generic (e.g. `Control`); which is why setting the Visible property works but not the LandingPage property.